# combining xmls files in a loop and removing the nodes not needed

Tags: c#, xml

Im trying to combine multiple xml files through a loops.
I put the first XML in a string then add the next one to the same string.
I do remove the xml declaration first before i add using

```
                   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(currentdaydata);
                    var declarations = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
                    .Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                    .ToList();


                    declarations.ForEach(x => doc.RemoveChild(x));
```

Each xml response is in the following format like the below but i cant seem to remove the root element.

```
xml 1 = <response><movie>....<movie></response>
xml 2 = <response><movie>....<movie></response>
xml 3 = <response><movie>....<movie></response>

outputdata += xml(i);

outputdata =
<response><movie>....<movie></response><response><movie>....<movie></response><response><movie>....<movie></response>
```

I tried to remove it using a string replace but no luck

```
outputdata.Replace("</response><response>", "");
```

....

Comment: Don't just tell us it failed ("but no luck").Tell us how it failed - the first step in diagnosing any problem is to look at the symptoms.

Comment: You have an array of elements at the root.  A well formed xml has only one root and not an array.  There are two solutions 1) Add a single root : string results = "<root> + your xml string + </root>; 2) Use xmlreader and set the xmlreadersettings to use FRAGMENT option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to manipulate XML as a string: sooner or later you'll get some input you can't handle, or you'll produce some output that your customers can't handle, and the questions to SO that result from this will keep us all busy for years. Always use a real XML parser, even for the simplest of jobs.

If you download an XQuery processor such as Saxon then you can do this as a one-liner:

```
<response>{$docs/response/*}</response>
```

where $docs is supplied as the sequence of parsed input documents,